# How to remove unusual characters from JSON dump in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, sentiment-analysis

I have been searching around for a good way to remove all unusual characters from a JSON dump of tweets that I am using to compile a dataset for sentiment analysis.

characters I am trying to remove = ンボ チョボ付 最安値

These characters appear in my tweet data and I am trying to remove them using regex but to no avail.

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data_path = 'twitter_data.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_text_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

for tweet in tweets_data:
    if tweet['text']:
        tweets_text_data.append(tweet['text'])

print(tweets_text_data)

with open('dataset_file', 'w') as dataset_file:
    writer = csv.writer(dataset_file)
    writer.writerow(tweets_text_data)
```

I tried using re.sub() to take away these charcters but it will not work. How can I make this work?

Comment: How do you define unusual characters?  Is it anything that's not ascii?  Anything that doesn't fit into cp1252?

Comment: I gave an example above of what I consider unusual. Anything not in the english language. My tweet json dump file has a lot of asian symbols in it. Numbers are also fine.

Comment: `tweets_text_data.append(tweet['text'].encode('cp1252', errors='ignore').decode('cp1252'))`.  Encoding `cp1252` supports characters in  Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, French, German, Dutch, English, Danish, Swedish, Norwegian, and Icelandic.  A slightly more restrictive encoding to try is `cp437`.  I don't recommend `ascii` because you will lose things like emdashes and accented characters. `errors='ignore'` means to skip characters that fall outside the encoding.  `errors='replace'` would put a `?` for bad characters instead.

Comment: You should change `open('dataset_file', 'w')` to `open('dataset_file', 'w', newline='')`.

Comment: This is great except it's missing ',' at the end of each text passage. Any ideas on how to fix that?